# Python-what causes this error on my dictionary and how can I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

My function is given a dictionary (db) and a list of strings (types). I need to take that list of strings and see if any of those strings are in the dictionary's values. If the string is in the value, I need to create a new dictionary and update it with items that contain that string in their values.

Ex:

```
types=['poison','Grass']
db={"Bulbasaur": (1, "Grass", "Poison", 45, 49, 49, 45, 1, False),}
d={"Bulbasaur": (1, "Grass", "Poison", 45, 49, 49, 45, 1, False)} #adds the info for that pokemon
```

I keep getting this error when I run my code:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

```
def pokemon_by_types(db,types):
    d={}
    for item in types:
        types=item
        for key,values in db.items():
            if types in values:
                d.update(key)
    return d
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it? It is actually a problem I have gotten on several of my other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dict.update()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) accepts another `dict` or an iterable of pairs as an argument. In your case however, `key` is a string. So maybe you meant:

```
d.update([(key, values)])
```

or simply:

```
d[key] = values
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thank you!